# The $PATH variable does not change after installing DB2 in openSUSE

Tags: linux, db2, opensuse, db2-luw

I try to install DB2 in openSUSE.(success in Centos)

After installation the `$PATH` does not change and I can't use `db2start`, `db2set` commands.

I don't know the `$PATH` for DB2.

The openSUSE version: leap-42.1

The DB2 batabase version: V9.7x64

Here is my `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
/home/mylinux/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Answer (score 1):

DB2-specific environment variables are set by the `db2profile` script that is installed in the directory called `sqllib` in the instance home. You need to execute (source) this script to set the variables in your shell session:

```
$ source /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
```

You can also add execution of the profile to your shell `.profile`.